# Aligning $A^x_y$?

Tags: symbols, formulas

Is it possible to obtain a variant of `$A^x_y$` so that `x` and `y` are slightly smaller, and so that the top of the `x` is as high as the top of the `A`, while the bottom of the `y` is as low as the bottom of the `A`?

Comment: Well you can create boxes and measure them manually, but this seems like an oddly specific request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No guess about the amount of raising.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$T$}%
  \vbox to \ht0{%
    \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}
    \vss
    \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}\vskip0pt
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$A\foo{x}{y}$ $B\foo{x}{y}$ $C\foo{g}{t}$

\Large

$A\foo{x}{y}$ $B\foo{x}{y}$ $C\foo{g}{t}$

\end{document}
```

As you see, the command behaves also in different type sizes.

[image]

Choose a better name than `\foo`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the name as a souvenir! :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

Naturally, the needed height adjustments very much depend on the math font that's in use and on the document's font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document} 
$A^x_y$ 
vs.\
$A^{\raisebox{1.4pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle x$}}%
  _{\raisebox{3.5pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle \smash{y}$}}$ 
\quad
$\displaystyle A^x_y$
vs.\
$\displaystyle A^{\raisebox{0.9pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle x$}}%
  _{\raisebox{3.5pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle \smash{y}$}}$
\end{document}
```